# Spring Boot Rest Application - Getting Internal Server Error-500

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest

I am using spring boot and Spring Data JPA in my project.

Sometimes what happens the android or iOS gets Internal Server Error message.

I am not getting what is the exact error. There is no exception logged in log files.

Though I save the request response in database what I get is below

> **requestPath-**/wordpower/error
>   **requestMethhod-** GET
>   **ResponseBody-**
>   {timestamp=Mon Mar 02 10:13:54 UTC 2020, status=500, error=Internal Server Error, message=No message available, path=/wordpower/wordpower/v1/getHomeScreenData}

Can anyone help me out what is the problem here?

Comment: Your URL is correct ? /wordpower/wordpower/v1/getHomeScreenData

Comment: Yes it is correct @MyTwoCents

Comment: Why request path contains /error ? is it the desired resource generally /error is used to give fallback to return an error message. This is very generic so there can any reason if code and configurations are correct, look another aspect if enough memory is available, server set up is proper or throwing some warning?

Comment: @RishabhSharma Try enabling the debug logs for spring and post them here. That could help us investigate as currently the provided information is too less to understand the cause.

Answer (score 0):

i got same error when i try to POST request .this error occurs due to same id in a database. by default the new generated id is 1 but if you previously added entiry with id 1 , then this error occurs. solution is simple change the id of previous entity to other than 1.